# Open Desktop Application using Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Is there a way to open Notepad application in users computer using Aura?

Comment: No. If Javascript allowed that, it would be a _massive_ security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can technically do this. However, please be aware that you're looking at a rather significant security risk if you do so. Please note that this requires OS-level modifications to make it work, so you'll need to have access to the users' machines (e.g. providing them a .reg file, or setting a GPO on an enterprise network to force this setting).

In order to make this work, you must first register a [handler with the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277284/2132791). From there, you can then create a link ([example in LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/TgIGwvJZ0/1/edit)) to the custom URL handler, and your program will launch after a confirmation dialog.

For the demo screenshot below, I used the following registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\notepad]
@="URL:Notepad Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\notepad\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\notepad\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\notepad\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\notepad\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe\" \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\" \"%5\" \"%6\" \"%7\" \"%8\" \"%9\""
```

[image: Open Notepad Dialog]

Comment: Well then, I stand corrected.